# trouble using relational operator (!=)

Tags: java

college student learning java. I am working on a homework assignment on creating class exceptions. For some reason my if statement seems to keep generating my class exception method. Take a look.

```
    public class ICDEDriver {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidDocumentCodeException {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            InvalidDocumentCodeException problem = new InvalidDocumentCodeException("this is my error message")

            System.out.println("Enter a valid document code: ");
            String code = scan.nextLine();

            if(code.charAt(0) != 'U' || code.charAt(0) != 'C' || code.charAt(0) != 'P')
                throw problem;

            System.out.println("End of main method");
        }
    }
```

So my issue is that when I enter a "valid document code" (document code must start with U, C, or P) it still triggers the InvalidDocumentCodeException. How can I fix it to where the if statement will accept U, C, or P as the first character? Thanks!

Comment: Reverse the logic, `if (code.charAt(0) != 'U' && code.charAt(0) != 'C' && ...)`

Comment: Pretend that the character is U. Which of the terms are true? What is the result of combining those values with OR?

Comment: You might also try having a look at what `System.out.println(true || false || false);` and `System.out.println(true && false && false);` prints

Answer (score 1):

Here try to use the && operator

```
if((code.charAt(0) != 'U' && code.charAt(0) != 'C' && code.charAt(0) != 'P'))
            throw problem;
```

The || operator does evaluate to true even if one side of the logic is false, && will make sure all of them are true.

Comment: ahh that did the trick, thanks for your help!